# Type single quotes in AucTeX

Tags: auctex

When type `"` in AucTeX, either ``` `` ``` or `''` is typed. How do I do similar action with single quotes? Typing `'` won't give me `` ` `` or `'`.

**EDIT** I'm not asking about the double quotes---I agree with what double quotes did and I just want to show that single quotes do not behave the same as double quotes, but I want single quotes to behave the same as double quotes.

My babel is English.

Comment: Which is the language option passed to babel? AUCTeX treaties quotes in a special way in some cases. If I remember correctly, double quotes " can't be used in a basic LaTeX document, you'd need to replace them with ``...'' anyway, in that case. Reading the manual is always useful, before asking a question.

Comment: Surely, `"` can be used in basic LaTeX. It produces the same result as `''`, which results in ” in the document. Because this is of limited usefulness, some babel packages will use `"` for entirely different purposes, however. (These days, I use utf8 for nearly all my LaTeX documents, and I type ‘single’ and “double” quotes directly.)

Comment: @giordano  See my edit.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen you're right.  I remembered that there was some problems connected with using `"`, but I couldn't check when I wrote the above comment.  You're right: the problem is that you always get the closing double quotes.

Comment: Single quote handling would have to be (slightly) more clever than double quote handling, because single quotes should be inserted verbatim inside formulas.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The same happens for double quotes.

Comment: @giordano Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from `TeX-insert-quote`:

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-insert-single-quote (force)
  "Insert the appropriate quotation marks for TeX.
Inserts ` or ' depending on the context.  With prefix argument
FORCE, always inserts ' characters."
  (interactive "*P")
  (if (or force
      ;; Do not insert TeX quotes in verbatim, math or comment constructs.
      (and (fboundp 'font-latex-faces-present-p)
           (font-latex-faces-present-p '(font-latex-verbatim-face
                         font-latex-math-face
                         font-lock-comment-face))
           (font-latex-faces-present-p '(font-latex-verbatim-face
                         font-latex-math-face
                         font-lock-comment-face)
                       (1- (point))))
      (texmathp)
      (and (TeX-in-comment) (not (eq major-mode 'doctex-mode))))
      (self-insert-command (prefix-numeric-value force))
    (TeX-update-style)
    (let* ((open-quote "`")
       (close-quote "'"))
      (insert (cond ((bobp)
             open-quote)
            ((= (preceding-char) (string-to-char TeX-esc))
             ?\')
            ((= (preceding-char) ?\")
             ?')
            ((save-excursion
               (forward-char (- (length open-quote)))
               (looking-at (regexp-quote open-quote)))
             (delete-char (- (length open-quote)))
             ?')
            ((save-excursion
               (forward-char (- (length close-quote)))
               (looking-at (regexp-quote close-quote)))
             (delete-char (- (length close-quote)))
             ?')
            ((save-excursion
               (forward-char -1)
               (looking-at "[ \t\n]\\|\\s("))
             open-quote)
            (t
             close-quote))))))

(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "'") 'mg-TeX-insert-single-quote))
```